# Applying platform constraints to all configurations

Tags: gradle

How do I inherit constraints from BOMs for all configurations in an ergonomic way ? The following is how I am currently doing it. I am on Gradle 6.6.1.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly(platform('x:y:z'))
    implementation(platform('x:y:z'))
    annotationProcessor(platform('x:y:z'))
    testAnnotationProcessor(platform('x:y:z'))
    testImplementation(platform('x:y:z'))
    testCompileOnly(platform('x:y:z'))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you *could* do it by abusing the `configurations.all` method like this:

```java
// Groovy DSL
configurations.all { config ->
    project.dependencies.add(config.name, project.dependencies.platform('x:y:z'))
}
```

But you don't need to add the platform to all those configurations in the first place. Because most of them are resolvable and extend both `api` and `implementation`, you typically only need to add it to one of those. The only exception is `annotationProcessor`, which is isolated (but is extended by `testAnnotationProcessor`). So you can still reduce it to:

```java
// Groovy DSL
dependencies {
   implementation platform('x:y:z') // or api
   annotationProcessor platform('x:y:z')
}
```

This is in my opinion more readable and more precise.

A common use case is for Spring Boot. It could look like this:

```java
// Groovy DSL
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
}

dependencies {
    // BOMS (Note that using the "BOM_COORDINATES" variable makes it match the version of the plugin)
    implementation platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)
    annotationProcessor platform(SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES)

    // Actual dependencies
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
}
```

Interestingly, there is a [Gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8723) on this exact use case. Here they explained that typically you don't need this functionality, and where you do it is better to be explicit about it rather than just "hammer" a set of dependency versions onto everything.